# Trying to quit out of script without having it continue asking the next questions. If user inputs quit command it should just end the and exit program

Tags: python, loops, exit

Quitting a program without having to continue through script

Comment: just add the if check for "x" right after you input that ...

Comment: Please show some code to illustrate what you are doing. This doesn't have to be your complete program, but enough to give us an idea of what you have. See [mcve] for some tips.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do is probably replace return with exit(). That will terminate your progam.